# Coin tossing game for winner of gold coins

Tags: probability

A and B start a game. Initially they start with some gold coins. Each round they toss a fair coin. If Head occurs B gives a gold coin to A and if tail occurs A gives a gold coin to B. The person who runs out of the gold coins looses. What is the probability that A wins the game given A has 5 gold coins and B has 3 gold coins.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem? You will often get better help on this site if you show your own efforts.

Comment: Did you do theory on Markov chains? It's a symmetric walk with absorbing boundaries.

Comment: Look at these [notes](http://www2.math.uu.se/~sea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf) the part on gamber's ruin seems applicable.

Comment: @paw88789 well I'm getting 1/8 {( sum 2nCn )/2^n} but the sum isn't converging

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 4 in [these notes](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf) shows that this probability is $\frac{5}{5+3}=\frac{5}{8}$ and the expected number of rounds (theorem 5) is $5\times 3 = 15$.